# Loading WPF-settings to readonly dictionary on startup always empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, settings

I'm trying to share my application-settings between different assemblies as readonly object (e.g. a `Dictionary)`.

The `Settings` are the default ones used by `WPF`-applications. I want to enable the user to changed some settings before starting the action inside the WPF-application.
I only need the current settings-values as `readonly` to send them to the other assemblies.

Currently I have this in my MainWindows `OnLoaded`-callback.

```
var t = Settings.Default.PropertyValues.Cast<SettingsPropertyValue>().ToDictionary(value => value.Name, value => value.PropertyValue);
```

`t` is the `Dicitionary` I want to share/pass to the other assemblies that work on them (but do not change them).

However, `Settings.Default.PropertyValues` is empty and so is `t`.

My MainWindow already has some user-interface(s) to set some of those values like:

```
Settings.Default.ProjectRootDirectory = newFolder;
Settings.Default.Save();

var t = Settings.Default.PropertyValues.Cast<SettingsPropertyValue>().ToDictionary(value => value.Name, value => value.PropertyValue);

Settings.Default.Reload();
```

After setting `Settings.Default.ProjectRootDirectory = newFolder`, `Settings.Default.PropertyValues` has all properties loaded correctly.

How can I have the current setting-values without setting one before?

Comment: You have in your app.config the settings saved? The settings get their default values if they neither could be loaded from App.config or user.config if it is a user configurable setting. How are you defining your  settings?

Comment: I define them via project-settings interface. It then get stored as `Settings.settings` in the projects `Properties` folder as xml and a `internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase` .cs-file

Comment: A dictionary is not editable in the settings gui. So I guess you do not have any dictionary settings inside it.

Comment: It's not about how I set the properties. It's about how to read them into a Dictionary, as they are empty as long as I don't set a value explicitly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89149/c-why-does-settings-propertyvalues-have-0-items