# Properties.Settings with ItemsControl can't show Value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, properties.settings

I want to iterate trough my Settings (two settings Files, Settings and Monitor) and Show them in an ItemsControl. The Problem is: I can only bind the DefaultValue (referenced to the Value Bound to the ItemsControl) and not the actual Value.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProjectPerformance.Views.Settings"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ProjectPerformance.Views"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectPerformance"
         xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:ProjectPerformance.Properties"
         xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="settingstringtemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DefaultValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}" x:Key="settinginttemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Red"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DefaultValue}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}" x:Key="settingbooleantemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DefaultValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:Settingstemplateselector x:Key="settingstemplateselector"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid TextElement.FontSize="20">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Settings" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="40" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel>
            <Expander FontSize="15">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20">General</TextBlock>
                </Expander.Header>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="lbGeneral" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource settingstemplateselector}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Properties}"/>
            </Expander>
            <Expander FontSize="15">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20">Monitor</TextBlock>
                </Expander.Header>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="lbMonitor" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource settingstemplateselector}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Monitor.Default}, Path=Properties}"/>
            </Expander>
            <Button x:Name="btnSave" Width="150" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Save" FontSize="15" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="btnSave_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnDebug" Width="150" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Monitor.Default}, Path=graph_size}" FontSize="15" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="btnDebug_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnRestart" Width="150" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Restart App" FontSize="15" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="btnRestart_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I think it could Work like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Monitor.Default}, Path={Binding Name}}"/>
```

But I don't know how to bind a value inside a Binding.

Comment: Binding to the current value requires to you to specify the actual name of the property as a constant: `{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Monitor.Default}, Path=SettingName}`. You cannot bind something to the `Path` property or set it dynamically in pure XAML.

Comment: Okay, so it's not possible to solve this without code behind? I can only retrieve the Settings Name or DefaultValue by binding it with {Binding Name}, but the Value I'm looking for is one Stage higher, because the Value I'd get with the specific name only like: {Binding Source={x:Static properties:Monitor.Default}, Path=graph_size} is it then possible to put multiple variables in the ItemsControl?

Comment: You can bind to `Monitor.Default.PropertyValues` to get the current `SettingsPropertyValue` values.

Comment: Yes, but not If I'm iterating trough the Settings with a ItemsControl. That is the hard part here..

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to to the `PropertyValues` property to get the current `SettingsPropertyValue` values, e.g.:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Monitor.Default}, Path=PropertyValues}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Property.DefaultValue}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding PropertyValue}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that for the `PropertyValues` property to actually return any values, you [apparently need to either set a property or retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89149/c-why-does-settings-propertyvalues-have-0-items) each property first. You could do this dynamically using some reflection:

```
foreach (System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property in Monitor.Default.Properties)
    typeof(Monitor).GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(Monitor.Default);
```

Comment: Technically yes.. But I need the Value to the Respective Setting which the ItemsControl is iterating at the moment.. so I need the relative value to the respective setting here

Comment: What? Relative to what? Instead of binding to `Properties`, you should bind to `PropertyValues`. What's the catch?